# JavaScript Regular Express both dotall and global flags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
#a
b

#c
d
```

I would like to break it up into sections beginning with `#`:

```
#a
b
```

and

```
#c
d
```

I have attempted this with a regular expression, but I find that I can’t get it working.

I though that the following would work:

```
var test='#a\nb\n#c\nd';
var re=/#.*?/gs;
var match=test.match(re);
alert(match.length);
alert(match);
```

That is, the `s` modifier matches through line breaks, and the `g` modifier picks up multiple instances. The `?` lazy quantifier should stop the `*` from going too far.

However, I find that when I use just `s`, it only goes to the end of the line.

Clearly there’s something I’m not getting about either the regular expression or the `match()` method.

By the way, I know that `s` is only a recent addition to JavaScript, but I’m working in Electron, where it is readily available.

Comment: *The `?` lazy quantifier should stop the `*` from going too far*  - no, it stops it right away.

Comment: Does the string have two new lines after `b`? in your example it does, in your code it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [I wrested with a bear once's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580466/11165090) assumes that you wish to break on the basis of line breaks, and the answer by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580237/11165090) is very good but it fails (at least in my opinion).

For example, if we use Wiktor's regex `/#.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*/g` on the string

```
#Section 1
This is one section

And this is also part of first sections

#Section 2
This is part of section two.
```

Then it will ignore the line "This is also part of second section." in its match. The reason is simply because his regex breaks on the basis of double `\r?\n`, and hence it will just ignore the that line.

I am assuming you want to something similar to what happens in markdown where the # are used to automatically detects the sections and heading.

If that is the case, then use the following regex: `/#.*(?:\r?\n(?!#).*)*/g` , it's a minor modification of Wiktor's great answer. And this matches the lines as (I hope) we wanted.

What it does is that it matches the whole section, and does a negative lookahead so that it doesn't include anything beyond the next section i.e., next # symbol at the beginning of the line.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/ai15fP/2

Comment: That was an excellent solution. When I simplified my test string, I over simplified it. I really wanted only the hash to signal a new section, and not line breaks. You picked that up.

Comment: @Manngo If the only goal is to split into sections at lines starting with # you may just use `test.split(/^(?=#)/m)`, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is too much for this job. Use built-in string functions.

```js
var str = `#a
b

#c
d`;

var chunks = str.split("\n\n");

console.log(chunks);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If the only goal is to split into sections at lines starting with `#` you may just use

```
test.split(/^(?=#)/m)
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var test="#a\nb\n\n#c\nd";
console.log(test.split(/^(?=#)/m))
```

The `.*?` at the end of the pattern never matches any chars because it is skipped and end of pattern signals the match lookup is complete.

Use

```
s.match(/#.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ai15fP/1)

**Details**

- `#`  -  a `#` char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` - an optional CR and then LF that are not followed with an optional CR and then LF
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars

Or, use `split` with `/(?:\r?\n){2,}/` that matches 2 or more line break sequences.

JS demo:

```js
var test="#a\nb\n\n#c\nd";

console.log(test.match(/#.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*/g));
console.log(test.split(/(?:\r?\n){2,}/));
```